Bonobo GIT Server and AD Users
Just two questions:

If I remove a user from AD, how long until the user is no longer displayed in the users on the server?  It seems like I removed a user from the AD group and their account is still displayed on the Bonobo Server.
Can you nest AD groups?

Thanks!
I tried removing the users from the AD group.  I also restarted IIS a few times to see if that would kickstart anything.  Adding users is almost instant, but removing seems to be the opposite.
